# ¿Como puedo hacer que la etiqueta form no ocupe mucho espacio?

Tags: html

Tengo problemas con la etiqueta form tengo un foreach y dentro del foreach esta la etiqueta form la cual obliga al foreach a poner cada carta debajo de una y no en la misma fila como van a ver a continuación[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es que queden en la misma fila y no una debajo de otra, a continuación les dejo el codigo que tengo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, te agradeceríamos que en vez de poner una imagen del código, lo copies y lo pegues en la pregunta. De otra forma será difícil que te contesten

Comment: No puedo hacer eso, por que no conoce la sintaxis me dice

Comment: De todas formas, creo que es un problema con alguna de las clases css que utilizas. Asegúrate que la clase del contenedor de la imagen tenga un `float:left`

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo, moví el primer div antes de form y eso fue todo